# R: How to run a loop after replicating rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, indexing

After replicating few data rows in a dataframe for specific reasons I have a dataset like the following:

```
1          Is John there in Greece?
1.1        Is John there in Greece?
2          I last saw him in Vancoover
2.1        I last saw him in Vancoover
2.2        I last saw him in Vancoover
3          I do not remember if I saw him in the congress in mykonos
4          Happy to see you again in Athens
4.1        Happy to see you again in Athens
4.2        Happy to see you again in Athens
4.3        Happy to see you again in Athens
```

My question is how can I use the FOR function:
   a. only for the integer numbers ("original rows")
   b. only for the decimal numbers ("replicated rows")
   c. for all the numbers as a sequence (original and replicated rows)

Comment: I suggest you reconsider your whole approach. The duplication of rows is not something you should do. Instead create a vector of row indices and duplicate elements of this index vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this to divide you dataframe in "integer" rownames and "decimal" rownames

```
# "a" is the original dataframe
id <- as.numeric(row.names(a))
a.int <- a[abs(id-round(id))<1e-6,]
a.dec <- a[abs(id-round(id))>1e-6,]
```

Comment: and afterwards, how can I loop a function for the a.dec dataframe? It would be something like for ( i in .... ..... ....) {}     ? Could I enter (i in 1.1 : 1.8 for instance? or 1.1 : 8.9) ?

Comment: `for(i in 1:nrow(a.dec)){ #some code}` But try as much as possible to avoid for loop in R. Most of the function works in the idea that your data are stored in vectors or dataframe. Look also at apply-like function i.e. sapply, lapply, apply, ...

Comment: Nicolas, thank you the answer. After creating a a.dec dataframe I have the nrows displayed as 3.1, 3.2 and so on. Is there any way to make them as simple integers?